# How do I fix this "TypeError: 'str' object is not callable" error?

Tags: python, string, user-interface, comparison, callable

I'm creating a basic program that will use a GUI to get a price of an item, then take 10% off of the price if the initial price is less than 10, or take 20% off of the price if the initial price is greater than ten:

```
import easygui
price=easygui.enterbox("What is the price of the item?")
if float(price) < 10:
    easygui.msgbox("Your new price is: $"(float(price) * 0.1))
elif float(price) > 10:
    easygui.msgbox("Your new price is: $"(float(price) * 0.2))
```

I keep getting this error though:

```
easygui.msgbox("Your new price is: $"(float(price) * 0.1))
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable`
```

Why am I getting this error?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You are trying to use the string as a function:

```
"Your new price is: $"(float(price) * 0.1)
```

Because there is nothing between the string literal and the `(..)` parenthesis, Python interprets that as an instruction to treat the string as a callable and invoke it with one argument:

```
>>> "Hello World!"(42)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

Seems you forgot to concatenate (and call `str()`):

```
easygui.msgbox("Your new price is: $" + str(float(price) * 0.1))
```

The next line needs fixing as well:

```
easygui.msgbox("Your new price is: $" + str(float(price) * 0.2))
```

Alternatively, use string formatting with [`str.format()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.format):

```
easygui.msgbox("Your new price is: ${:.2f}".format(float(price) * 0.1))
easygui.msgbox("Your new price is: ${:.2f}".format(float(price) * 0.2))
```

where `{:02.2f}` will be replaced by your price calculation, formatting the floating point value as a value with 2 decimals.

Answer (score -1):

this part :

`"Your new price is: $"(float(price)`

asks python to call this string:

`"Your new price is: $"`

just like you would a function:
`function( some_args)` 
which will ALWAYS trigger the error:

`TypeError: 'str' object is not callable`